# Wordpress display by custom meta value, add_query_var

Tags: php, wordpress, function, loops, advanced-custom-fields

I have a blog page that lists my post types by title; essentially I am trying to add a way for the user to be able to toggle order by title (easy) and custom meta key(by state).

I am using [Advanced Custom Fields](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) for the meta key. The slug is  `state-code`:

`$state_code = types_render_field("state-code", array());`

I  was thinking since there are only 2 options I would add a button that when clicked reloads the page with a URL query (eg, *example.com/?state*) to display a separate loop.

-functions.php file (init add_query_wp)

```
add_action( 'init', 'add_query_var' );
function add_query_var() {
    global $wp;
    $wp->add_query_var( 'state' );
}
```

-Code so far

```
$state_code = types_render_field("state-code", array());

$args = array( 'post_type' => 'store','posts_per_page' => 100, 'orderby' => 'title', 'order' => "ASC" );
if(get_query_var('state') !== '') {
    $args['orderby'] = 'meta_value';
    $args['meta_key'] = $state_code;
    $args['meta_value'] = get_query_var('state');
} else $args['orderby'] = 'title';

$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
```

I know this isn't right, but I'm not even sure how to proceed from here. Like I said, I would imagine a button that would reload the page with the query string to show the *state* query.

That being said, am I going about this the wrong way? Is there an easier way for the user to toggle between `orderby: title` or `orderby: state`?

Comment: instead of using add_query_var(), try ajax to execute above code with order by state, or title.@VCP

Comment: Create 2 separate pages with same codes and only the order parameter will be different, and then on click of the sort button redirect to another page.

Comment: Looking at your code, you don't seem to be using Advanced Custom Fields but [Types](https://wordpress.org/plugins/types). I'd suggest you to edit your post and your question tags.